# Obscure text bool value is not updating in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, state, pin-code

I am using [pin_code_text_field](https://pub.dev/packages/pin_code_text_field) package to create pin code textfields. But when I was updating the bool value used to obscure text. Bool value is not updating in pin code fields until I click on textfields.

Code was added below:

```
bool pinWasObscured = true;


Row(
     children: [
        PinCodeTextField(
        maxLength: 4,
        hideCharacter: pinWasObscured,
        highlight: true,
        highlightAnimation: true,
        highlightAnimationBeginColor: Colors.black,
        highlightAnimationEndColor: Colors.white,
        highlightAnimationDuration: Duration(seconds: 5),
        highlightColor: Color(0xFFF37021),
        pinBoxDecoration: ProvidedPinBoxDecoration.underlinedPinBoxDecoration,
        maskCharacter: "*",
        pinTextStyle: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 15.sp,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            ),
        pinBoxWidth: SizeConfig.blockSizeHorizontal! * 12,
        pinBoxHeight: SizeConfig.blockSizeHorizontal! * 10,
        autofocus: false,
        controller: pinController,
        defaultBorderColor: Colors.black26,
       ),
        SizedBox(width: 10),
        IconButton(
         icon: pinWasObscured
                ? Icon(Icons.visibility_off_outlined)
                : Icon(Icons.visibility_outlined),
          onPressed: () {
                  setState(() {
                        pinWasObscured = !pinWasObscured;
                              });
                            },
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
```

Comment: The way this code is written, it looks like `pinWasObscured` is declared in the build method - is that the case?

Comment: no. Declared  outside the build .

Answer (score -1):

the issue is that you are also updating the value of the  "**hideCharacter**" on the click of item. you dont have to update the **hideCharacter** value everytime.
instead you have to set the value to true if you want to hide the character and false to show.

Comment: I need to update the hideCharacter value. Sometimes need to show pin and sometimes no need to show like.